# For each dict in list, extract data into another list of dict

Tags: python

I've been trying to find a way to do this, but can't seem to find a solution.

I have a list that contains a load of dictionaries, I want to go through each dictionary in the list to extract the values to form a smaller list contains the data in need.

The data is formed:

```
[{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Product Evaluation', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': <Project: C>},{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Community', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': <Project: C>},{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Marketing', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': <Project: C>},{'q_rounded': 0, 'title': 'Product Evaluation', 'project': <Project: D>}]
...
```

I want to group the final score for each title for each project into a single list

```
[{project_name, score 1, score 2, score 3...},
{project_name, score 1, score 2, score 3}
...
]
```

Is this even possible to do?

**Update**

My current list contains loads of dicts that show a score for an area of a project.

For example. Project1 has a score for 5 different areas and therefore my list of dicts has 5 seperate dicts just for this 1 project.

```
[{projectName1, Score 1},
{projectName1, score 2},
projectname1, score 3}...
}]
```

I'm trying to take each dictionary that relates to a project and build 1 list for each project

So i should end up with:

```
[{project1, score1, score2, score3
}...]
```

Which will end up giving me a list of dicts that will contain a single dict for every project that contains all the scores.

```
[{project1, score1, score2, score3
},
{project2, score1, score2, score3...]
```

The original list of dicts is made by:

```
results.append({'title':q.title,"project_image":project.image,'final_score':final_score,"project_name":project.name,"project_id":project.id})
```

**Update**

I'm trying to end up with a list of the project, and its values for each area. Not a dict.

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example? Input and expected output. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: sure, ill update now

Comment: Please provide a CONCRETE example. Also, `{a, b, c}` is not a dictionary but a set. A dictionary is like this: `{a: b, c: d}`

Comment: I've added my query that shows how the data is formed within each dict

Comment: You're still showing us sets, not dictionaries.

Comment: The current data is `[{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Product Evaluation', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': <Project: C>},{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Community', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': <Project: C>},{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Marketing', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': <Project: C>},{'q_rounded': 0, 'title': 'Product Evaluation', 'project': <Project: D>}]`

Comment: Which is think is multiple dicts within a list

Comment: I'm trying to get [[ProjectC, 100,5,5,5,0,[projectD, 100,...]]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing scores are an inner property of `project` object and you can try using list comprehension to do something like this:

```
output_list = [{'project_name':inner_dict.get('title'), 'scores': [inner_dict.get('project').scores]} for inner_dict in original_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all dictionaries and get the required info. Based on the output example, I would however store them in a dictionary of lists instead of a list of dictionaries (see example below).

Used input:

```
input = [{'q_rounded': 100,
          'title': 'Product Evaluation',
          'final_score': 5.0,
          'project': "C"},
         {'q_rounded': 100,
          'title': 'Community',
          'final_score': 5.0,
          'project': "C"},
         {'q_rounded': 100,
          'title': 'Marketing',
          'final_score': 5.0,
          'project': "C"},
         {'q_rounded': 0,
          'title': 'Product Evaluation',
          'final_score': 3.0,
          'project': "D"}]
```

Code:

```
output = {}
for entry in input:
    name = entry["project"]
    if name in output:
        output[name].append(entry["final_score"])
    else:
        output[name]= [entry["final_score"]]
```

Resulting output:

```
output = {'C': [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 'D': [3.0]}
```

Comment: I think this is what im after, but for some reason, i just get `{'ProjectName': [5.0]}